# In Facebook, how can I hide relationship status, profile pictures, etc?

Tags: facebook, privacy, status

It seems like there are a number of pieces of data that is hard to understand how to control privacy on.

How can I hide from the public:

1. Relationship Status
2. Profile Picture

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have *Timeline* (which will become default in the near future):

For Relationship Status:

1. Login to Facebook
2. Go to your profile (*Timeline*)
3. Click on **About** underneath your picture
   [image]
4. Scroll down to **Relationships and Family**
5. Click **Edit**
   [image]
6. In the popup, click on the privacy icon on the right, next to *Relationship status*
   [image]
7. Choose **Only Me** (or appropriate)
   [image]
8. Click **Save**

The profile picture can't be hidden, it's public. Even if you hide the Profile Pictures album, the current profile picture remains visible.